# How to find Parameters in nonlinear Regression Model?

Tags: matlab, regression, nonlinear-optimization

I have a nonlinear Regression Model with eleven observations of $x,y$. How do I find the parameters $a,b,c,d$ of the model:
$ y=f(x)=a + b \sin  cx e^{dx}$
by using the function:
$$\Phi(a, b, c, d)=\sum_{i = 1}^{11}{(y_i - f(x_i))^2}$$
Subject to the following conditons: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial a} &=& 0 \\ 
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial b} &=& 0 \\ 
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial c} &=& 0 \\ 
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial d} &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
How can one implement it in Matlab and is there a possible Algorithm, how can I ensure measurement precision?
Any help would be good, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [fmincon](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) or [lsqnonlin](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) and take your derivatives by hand. Levenberg-Marquardt is normally the method of choice for non-linear least-squares, you can do it with lsqnonlin. Mathematical precision is measured by your cost function $\Phi(a, b, c, d)$